# Terminal Profiles Keyboard Action

Tags: terminal, keyboard, keybindings

Where can I find detailed technical documentation describing what the elements of the GUI found in Terminal.app -> Settings -> Profiles -> keyboard?

The documentation that pops up when the `?` button clicked is typical for Apple.  It explains how to open the dialog from which I just opened the so-called help.  It explains that + means add and - means remove.

There must be some documentation describing what exactly the "keys" being +'ed and -'ed are.  And what the columns of that table are?  And what exactly does `\033[17~` is.  Where do I find out how to decode this "Action".  What does it do?

To be clear, I am asking to be refered to detailed documentation.  I am not asking that you explain anything.  The questions in the previous paragraphs are rhetorical examples of the type of questions I would like the documentation I seek to answer.

[image]
[image]